# Almost Complex Integrability and Algebraic Varieties

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-manifolds, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $J$ be an almost complex structure on an algebraic variety $V$. As we all know, $J$ comes from a complex structure if the Nijenhuis tensor of $J$ vanishes. What I would like to know is if there exists a simpler characterisation of integrability than this for varieties (as opposed to general manifolds).

Comment: Do you mean smooth algebraic varieties? 

Comment: When you say that $V$ is an algebraic variety, are you assuming that it is complex-algebraic (i.e., already has a complex structure), and that $J$ is an additional almost-complex structure?

Comment: @ Zsolt: By smooth do you mean non-singular?

@Scott: By algebraic variety I mean algebraic variety in the simplest sense - no assumptions. To paraphrase my question, I am asking when you can have an almost complex structure on a variety without it being a complex manifold.

Comment: @Janos: If you want equivalent conditions to the Nijenhuis tensor vanishing then one is that the induced $\bar \partial$ operator defines a complex, i.e. that $\bar \partial^2 = 0$. Another one is that the exterior derivative decomposes as $d = \partial + \bar \partial$. If you want explicit examples of almost complex manifolds that are not complex, that's going to be more difficult, see the answers to http://tinyurl.com/4zrkar6

Comment: No, wait, do you want to hit two birds with one stone and get integrability for the almost complex structure *and* projectivity of the resulting complex manifold in one swoop? I'm not sure that's going to be doable... just look at two-dimensional tori. You can realize any complex torus as an integrable complex structure on $M = \mathbb R^2/\mathbb Z^2$, but not all tori are projective. Given an arbitrary integrable complex structure on $M$, I don't know how to link its properties to the question of projectivity of the torus.

Comment: @Gunnar: No I'm not so worried about whether it's projective or not. You're first answer seems to be what I'm looking for. Just one question: How do you define $\partial$ and $\overline{\partial}$  from $J$ – Janos Erdmann 0 secs ago

Comment: .... and do you have a reference for a proof that each of these conditions implies a complex structure?

Comment: There is a simpler criterion that does integrability and Kählerness in one step: if there is both a Riemann metric $g$ and an almost complex structure $J$ and $\nabla J =0$ (i.e., $J$ is parallel w.r.t. the Levi-Civita connection of the Riemann metric), then $J$ is automatically integrable and $g$ is a kähler metric.

Comment: @Gunnar: complex tori of complex dimension $1$ *are* automatically projective (they are smooth elliptic curves). In general, compact Riemann surfaces are smooth projective algebraic curves...

Comment: @unknowngoogle: Thanks for catching that, I meant to put a $M = \mathbb R^4 / \mathbb Z^4$, but I've been typing similar things for the case of elliptic curves for a week. By now I have to make a very conscious effort to state things in other than real dimension 2.

Comment: @ Johannes: So you mean, given a complex structure $J$ and a metric $g$ compatible with $J$, we have a Kahler manifold if, for the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ of $g$, we have $\nabla(J) = 0$, then the manifold is Kahler?

Comment: ... and how exactly does $\nabla$ act on $J$?

Comment: $\nabla$ acts on all tensor bundles of $TM$, in particular on $End (TM)$, where $J$ lives in. The formula is $\nabla_X J(Y) = (\nabla_ X J)(Y) + J \nabla_X Y$. If $\nabla J=0$, then $J$ is integrable; that is what I said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want equivalent conditions to the Nijenhuis tensor vanishing then one is that the induced $\bar \partial$ operator defines a complex, i.e. that $\bar \partial^2 = 0$. Another one is that the exterior derivative decomposes as $d = \partial + \bar \partial$. If you want explicit examples of almost complex manifolds that are not complex, that's going to be more difficult, see the answers to tinyurl.com/4zrkar6

To find the $\bar \partial$ operator associated to an almost complex structure $J$ on a smooth manifold $M$, one needs to note that $J$ induces a splitting $T_M \otimes \mathbb C = T^{1,0} \oplus T^{0,1}$ of the tangent bundle into $i$ and $-i$ eigenvectors (the eigenspaces being marked with $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, respectively).

The same thing happens on the level of 1-forms (and indeed on the level of $k$-forms): they split into $(p,q)$-forms like on complex manifolds. If $\pi^{p,q} : \bigwedge^k T_M \to \bigwedge^{p,q} T_M$ is the projection onto the space of $(p,q)$-forms, then the $\bar \partial : \bigwedge^{p,q} T_M \to \bigwedge^{p,q+1} T_M$ operator associated to $J$ is $\bar \partial_J = \pi^{p,q+1} \circ d$.

Once one does the calculations this comes out to
$$ \bar \partial \alpha = \frac 1 2 \left( d \alpha + i d J \alpha \right) $$
for a $(p,q)$-form $\alpha$. A similar formula holds for the $\partial$ operator, you just have to change $i$ to $-i$. (I may have confounded the signs here.)

A very good reference for the linear algebra parts (i.e. most of this) is Chapter 2 of Huybrecht's "Complex geometry".

For the conditions equivalent to the vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor I seem to remember the first chapter of http://tinyurl.com/4cqspu7 Moroianu's notes on Kahler geometry being very helpful when I went through this a couple of months ago.

Finally, on why the vanishing of the Nijenhuis tensor implies that we indeed have a complex structure I recommend Demailly's book - Chapter 8, section 11 (page 396) has all the details:
http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf