# Global Definition of the Almost Complex Structure of a Complex Manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Motivated by this [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/56182/almost-complex-integrability-and-algebraic-varieties), I began to wonder if there is a global definition of the almost complex structure of a complex manifold. It is (almost) always presented as multiplication by complex $i$ on the tangent space, and then globalized. Using the  formulae given earlier
$$
\overline{\partial}\omega = \frac{1}{2}(\text{d}\omega + i \text{d}(J\omega)), 
$$
and
$$
\partial \omega = \frac{1}{2}(\text{d}\omega - i \text{d}(J\omega)), 
$$
it is easy to see that 
$$
-\frac{i}{2}d\omega = d(J\omega).
$$
Thus, $J\omega = -\frac{i}{2}\omega + \omega'$, where $\omega'$ is some closed form. What this $\omega'$ is, however, I cannot see.

Comment: Isn't defining an almost complex structure $J$ as a section of $End(T_M)$ which satisfies $J^2 = -id_{T_M}$ pretty global? Also, to derive your last equation you need to know that $d = \partial + \bar \partial$, which is equivalent to $J$ being integrable. And what is your $\omega$?

Comment: @Gunnar For your first question: The definition of an almost complex structure $J$ is certainly global, but the construction of the canonical $J$ for a complex manifold is what I'm interested in. Surely, there is more than one almost complex structure on a complex maniold, ie $J^2 = $id$_{T_M}$ does not define it uniqely. So I suppose my question is how does one identify the cancoical one globally?

For your second: As I said just above, I am assuming that my manifold is complex, and so, I certainly have $\text{d}=\partial + \overline{\partial}$.

Comment: .... I mean of course canonical not cancoical. 

Comment: Indeed it is often the case that there more than one **complex** structure on a complex manifold. In any case, once you fix a complex structure, the almost complex structure associated to it is multiplication by i. How is this definition not global?

Comment: Really, it's that simple, $J(\omega) = i.\omega$?

Comment: It just doesn't seem right to me that for any smooth function $f$, we have $i\partial(f) = \sum_{j=1}^k g_j \overline{\partial}(h_j)$, for some other smooth functions $g_i,h_i$.

Comment: I think you should rewrite your question and explain your notation. I do not understand what $\omega$, $g_j$ and $h_j$ are. Furthermore I do not understand what your last comment about deriving a function has to do with the issue at hand.

Comment: I'm looking at the $J$ as an operator on $\Omega^1(M)$. Then if $f$ is a smooth function, $\partial(f)$ is a (1,0)-form. Operating on  $\partial(f)$ by $J$ will, if I understand it correctly, will send it to the $\Omega^{(0,1)}(M)$ forms, which are spanned by elements of the form $\overline{\partial}(g)$, for $g$ also a smooth function. Thus, if $J$ is just multiplication by $i$, we get my statement above.

Comment: The whole question seems to stem from a misunderstanding. $J$ is an endomorphism of $TM$. It acts on the dual space $T^*M$ by the dual map, and on $k$-forms (possibly complex-valued) by multilinear extension.

$\Lambda^{1,0}T^*M$ is by definition the $+i$ eigenspace of $J$ in $T^*M \otimes \mathbb{C}$,
and $\Lambda^{0,1}T^*M$ the $-i$ eigenspace. $J$ acts on $\Lambda^{p,q}T^*M$ as multiplication by $i^{p-q}$.

The $(1,0)$-part of a 1-form $\alpha$ is $\frac{1}{2}(\alpha - iJ\alpha)$, so
$\partial f = \frac{1}{2}(df + iJ(df))$ for a function. The expressions in the question seem incorrect.

Comment: Ok, I see now what's going on. Thanks a lot Johannes. Sorry for asking a question before I understood waht I was asking about. I think the best thing to do with this question would be to **close it**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the construction of the canonical $J$ for a complex manifold is what I'm interested in

Given a complex manifold, you have a bundle of (1,0)-forms within complexified 1-forms
which is generated (over $C^\infty$) by differentials of holomorphic functions. This gives
a decomposition of 1-forms  tensor C into (1,0) and (0,1)-part. Your I is an operator
which is equal to $\sqrt -1$ on (1,0)-forms and $-\sqrt -1$ on (0,1)-forms. It is in
fact real, hence defines a real endomorphism of TM, squared to -Id.

Comment: This definition is of course also local; there do not need to exist nontrivial holomorphic functions. But: complex structures are by definition a local thing, anyway.